# Capture double click tray icon event

Tags: c#

I tried to search for this but to no avail. I am fairly new to visual studio 2015 and trying to capture a double click event on a tray icon created in my program. My program minimizes to the tray but then I want to double click it to maximize again. I already have the code to maximize the window just do not know where to capture the doubleclick.

Comment: post what you have done so far.

Comment: The NotifyIcon class has a DoubleClick event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did to solve this:

I added this to my code:

```
this.notifyIcon1.MouseDoubleClick += new system.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.notifyIcon1_DoubleClick);
```

Comment: This can be shortened to just `this.notifyIcon1.MouseDoubleClick += this.notifyIcon1_DoubleClick;`